# How to sort list of dates in php?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, date

```
foreach ($programs as $key => $program) {
  $mp4FullPath_date = date("F d Y H:i:s", filemtime($src_dir.DS.$mp4_files[$key])); // **Line A**
  print_r($mp4FullPath_date); //Added for debugging purpose **Line B**
}
```

Line B prints the following date/time on page load (It can be more than three as well. At this moment, it is three.):

```
May 01 2019 14:56:56 April 30 2019 10:21:12  April 30 2019 10:21:12
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what code I need to add in between **LineA** and **LineB** so that on debug at **LineB** it print the dates in ascending order like this:

```
 April 30 2019 10:21:12  April 30 2019 10:21:12 May 01 2019 14:56:56
```

Comment: just apply the custom function you got from the previous post and apply it in your array. provided it is indeed a collection of dates which `strtotime` can parse

Comment: it should sort the dates as expected

Comment: @Ghost i am wondering if you can let me know in an answer how can we do that or demo [here](https://3v4l.org)

Comment: So you get one string with the three date-values, and you want to sort them? Or do you get 3 separate iteraions that prints `$mp4FullPath_date`?

Comment: i am getting this **May 01 2019 14:56:56 April 30 2019 10:21:12 April 30 2019 10:21:12**  from this php code `$mp4FullPath_date = date("F d Y H:i:s", filemtime($src_dir . DS . $mp4_files[$key]));   // Line A`

Comment: But is that inside a loop? Then just add `$arr[] = $mp4FullPath_date;` in the loop?

Comment: What I want is that it should be sorted. I want the following o/p `April 30 2019 10:21:12  April 30 2019 10:21:14 May 01 2019 14:56:56`

Comment: If you're not answering the questions, its hard for us to help you. So I'll ask again: Is that first part (your definition of "Line A"), inside a loop? If yes, then read my previous comment, add it to the array, then use `usort()` as you have in your second part and you're done.

Comment: Yes, I am modifying the question.

Comment: Like this ? `$arr = $mp4FullPath_date; // Line B
function date_sort($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b);
}
usort($arr, "date_sort");
print_r($arr);` Let me know.

Comment: The values here are not fixed `May 01 2019 14:56:56 April 30 2019 10:21:12 April 30 2019 10:21:12` It can be more than 3 as well. It can be 2 as well.

Comment: @flash There's an answer below which should do exactly what you're looking for. Suggest you try it out - and if its what you're looking for, accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Based on what I see/understand you're trying to sort the `$mp4FullPath_date` that's a single date, not an array.

Add the dates to an array, then use your `usort()` with `date_sort()` on that array.

```
function date_sort($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b);
}

$dates = [];
foreach ($programs as $key => $program) {
    $mp4FullPath_date = date("F d Y H:i:s", filemtime($src_dir.DS.$mp4_files[$key]));
    $dates[] = $mp4FullPath_date;
}

usort($dates, "date_sort");
echo implode(" ", $dates);
```

Comment: On adding `print_r($dates);` after `$dates[] = $mp4FullPath_date;` I am getting the following o/p: 
`Array
(
    [0] => May 01 2019 14:56:56
)
Array
(
    [0] => May 01 2019 14:56:56
    [1] => April 30 2019 10:21:12
)
Array
(
    [0] => May 01 2019 14:56:56
    [1] => April 30 2019 10:21:12
    [2] => April 30 2019 10:21:12
)`

Comment: i am not sure why its printing three times above.

Comment: In layman language, I want this to be sorted in ascending order `May 01 2019 14:56:56 April 30 2019 10:21:12 April 30 2019 10:21:12`.

Comment: @flash if you want to change the order just swap the position in `date_sort` so you have `return strtotime($b) - strtotime($a);` instead of `return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b);`

Comment: No i don't want to change the order. I want to dates to show up in ascending order. I have modified my to make it more clear.

Comment: So the output from this is not what you expect? https://3v4l.org/KMiMh (code from above but added some test data and also printing the pure array in addition to just printing the imploded string)

Comment: In the code [here](https://3v4l.org/NpNDt). Line C returns the following o/p: `Array ( [0] => May 01 2019 14:56:56 ) Array ( [0] => May 01 2019 14:56:56 [1] => April 30 2019 10:21:12 ) Array ( [0] => May 01 2019 14:56:56 [1] => April 30 2019 10:21:12 [2] => April 30 2019 10:21:12 )`

Comment: I am wondering, why its returning the array in weird fashion ?

Comment: Is there any way, if its can take the last one ? Let me know.

Comment: put the `print_r()` outside the loop and the `$dates = [];` declaration before the loop as [here](https://3v4l.org/A06Xt), since you have the print inside the loop it dumps the full data each iteration